# Java REST API that uses OpenAM token to determine user?

Tags: java, rest, openam

I am having trouble being able to validate a users token with OpenAM. Particularly what type of Agent I should create. Is there anyone that can recommend a solution?

Essentially the REST API will read the users OpenAM tokenid and validate the token with OpenAM which then will return data which contains a username. That username can be used in the REST API method to identify who is accessing the method.

Even more simplified is how can I use a OpenAM token to get the OpenAM user info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with with idFromSession:

```
curl --request POST \
 --header "iplanetdirectorypro: AQIC5wM2LY4SfczUFNs-TJwFrCVAKgR0NulIAyNaIkQmjis.*AAJTSQACMDEA
 AlNLABQtNTQ3NDE2Njc5ODk4MjYzMzA2MQ..*" \
 --header "Content-Type: application/json"
http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/json/users?_action=idFromSession
```

Then in my java REST API method I used:

```
String httpsURL = "https://openam.example.com:8080/openam/json/users?_action=idFromSession";
URL url = new URL(httpsURL);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

//add request headers
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

// Add session token as header
con.setRequestProperty("iplanetdirectorypro", "AQIC5wM2LY4SfczUFNs-TJwFrCVAKgR0NulIAyNaIkQmjis.*AAJTSQACMDEA
     AlNLABQtNTQ3NDE2Njc5ODk4MjYzMzA2MQ..*");

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
// Read output
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

Based the HTTP POST off of: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following endpoints:

1. Authenticate user:

   ```
   curl --request POST --header "X-OpenAM-Username: demo" \
   --header "X-OpenAM-Password: changeit" \
   --header "Content-Type: application/json"      
   "http://openam.example.com:8080/sso/json/authenticate"

   {"tokenId":"AQIC5wM2LY4SfcyTReB5nbrLt3QaH-7GhPuU2-uK2k5tJsA.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABMyOTUxODgxODAwOTE0MTA4NDE3*","successUrl":"/sso/console"}
   ```
2. Validate token:

   ```
   curl --request POST \
   --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
   "http://openam.example.com:8080/sso/json/sessions/AQIC5wM2LY4SfczadxSebQWi9UEyd2ZDnz_io0Pe6NDgMhY.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABM3MTMzMTYwMzM1NjE4NTE4NTMx*?_action=validate"

   {"valid":true,"uid":"demo","realm":"/"}
   ```
3. Get profile attributes:

   ```
   curl --request GET \
   --header "iPlanetDirectoryPro: AQIC5wM2LY4SfczadxSebQWi9UEyd2ZDnz_io0Pe6NDgMhY.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABM3MTMzMTYwMzM1NjE4NTE4NTMx*" \
   "http://openam.example.com:8080/sso/json/users/demo"

   {"username":"demo","realm":"/","uid":["demo"],"userPassword":["{SSHA}cIgTNGHWd4t4Ff3SHa6a9pjMyn/Z3e3EOp5mrA=="],"sn":["demo"],"createTimestamp":["20160406210602Z"],"cn":["demo"],"givenName":["demo"],"inetUserStatus":["Active"],"dn":["uid=demo,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"],"objectClass":["devicePrintProfilesContainer","person","sunIdentityServerLibertyPPService","inetorgperson","sunFederationManagerDataStore","iPlanetPreferences","iplanet-am-auth-configuration-service","organizationalperson","sunFMSAML2NameIdentifier","oathUser","inetuser","forgerock-am-dashboard-service","iplanet-am-managed-person","iplanet-am-user-service","sunAMAuthAccountLockout","top"],"universalid":["id=demo,ou=user,dc=openamcfg,dc=example,dc=com"]}
   ```

Answer (score -1):

don't you need cookies to be set ..

```
   Response fieldResponse = given().auth().oauth2( oAuthLogin.getToken())
                .config(new RestAssuredConfig().
                        decoderConfig(
                                new DecoderConfig("UTF-8")
                        ).encoderConfig(
                        new EncoderConfig("UTF-8", "UTF-8")
                ))
                .header("iplanetDirectoryPro", oAuthLogin.getToken())
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
//                .contentType("application/json")
                .body(myRequest).with()
                .when()
                .post(dataPostUrl)
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .log().ifError()
                .statusCode(200)
                .extract().response();
```

is failing as bad request 400.Same content header is working in postman.
Only difference i see is cookie.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3sO9.png)
Working as per postman

Not working one which used restassured framework [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kVdY.png)

Comment: Does this answer have anything to do with OpenAM?   I'm not seeing how it answers the question.